# Can I export a render of the material view mode?

Tags: rendering

So as you probably know, Blender allows different viewport shading mode (e.g. solid, wireframe, etc), and I was wondering if I could render / export an animation of the material view mode.

I want to do this in order to show the animation of my project without having to wait for a full render or using an extremely low sample rate (which, quite frankly, looks disgusting).

Is this at all possible?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, it is possible, it is called OpenGL rendering. The leftmost buttons on the bottom of the 3D View will do this:

[image]

You will get a rendering of the current viewport, either a still picture (left) or the full animation (right). Just switch to Material view and press the button.